# last element working in each loop

Tags: jquery

I wanted an animation where i assign random left and top values to divs and animate them, but also wanted the animation to restart after finishing. so i fired the animate function inside itself, but after the first animation, only the last repeating div element was animating. I did like this:

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

$(".dot").each(function(){

    var abc = getRandomArbitrary(0,100);
    var xyz = getRandomArbitrary(0,100);
    var aaa = getRandomArbitrary(0,100);
    var yyy = getRandomArbitrary(0,100);
    $(this).css({"left": abc+"%", "top": xyz+"%"})
    $thiss = $(this);
    for(var i=0; i< $(".dot").length;i++){
        function anim(){
            $thiss.animate({"left":yyy+"%", "top": aaa+"%"},1000,function(){
                anim();
            });
            console.log(i)
        }
    }
    anim();
});
```

**html:**

```
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
```

**css:**

```
.dot{width: 8px; height: 8px; border-radius: 100%; background: red; position: absolute;}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qfcmfzw7/
fiddle where i didnot use the 'for':  https://jsfiddle.net/744sx34v/

Comment: for demo use `<>` snippet

Comment: can you pls make a clarity in fiddle link provided

Answer (score 3):

Move the functionality to a seperate function and call it within the loop:

```js
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }
    
    function anim(object){
    
        var aaa = getRandomArbitrary(0,100);
         var yyy = getRandomArbitrary(0,100);

         object.animate({"left":yyy+"%", "top": aaa+"%"},1000,function(){
              anim(object);
         });
     }
         
     $(".dot").each(function(){
     
        // set the initial position of each div
        var abc = getRandomArbitrary(0,100);
        var xyz = getRandomArbitrary(0,100);
       $(this).css({"left": abc+"%", "top": xyz+"%"});
        
        // call the animate function which calls itself recursively
       anim($(this));
     });
```

```css
.dot{width: 8px; height: 8px; border-radius: 100%; background: red; position: absolute;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @KAD !

Comment: You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `for` loop and need to recursively call the `animate()` for a specific element which also Randomly sets the `top` and `left` CSS property.

```js
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

$(".dot").each(function() {
  //Initially set left and top afterwards animate will take care of it
  var left = getRandomArbitrary(0, 100);
  var top = getRandomArbitrary(0, 100);
  $this = $(this);
  $this.css({
    "left": left + "%",
    "top": top + "%"
  })
  animate($this);
});

function animate($this) {
  var left = getRandomArbitrary(0, 100);
  var top = getRandomArbitrary(0, 100);
  $this.animate({
    "left": left + "%",
    "top": top + "%"
  }, 1000, function() {
    animate($this);
  });
}
```

```css
.dot {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot"></div>
```